# Allow full urls starting with http, https or www in ping

Tags: bash, ping

I often have the problem that I have a URL and want to ping the domain of that address.

Is there an option to allow ping to use only the domain part of a URL that is given as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do all of those transformations in bash, with [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
pingd() (
  domain=$1

  # allow 'http' or 'www' to match any upper- or lower-case versions
  # (bash version 4.4-alpha and later)
  shopt -s nocasematch

  # strip any leading http(s)
  domain=${domain/#http:\/\/}
  domain=${domain/#https:\/\/}

  # strip any leading user:pass@
  domain=${domain/#*:*@/}

  # strip the trailing slash onwards
  domain=${domain/%\/*/}

  # strip any trailing port
  domain=${domain/%:*/}

  # strip any remaining leading www
  domain=${domain/#www./}

  ping "$domain"
)
```

Examples (with `echo ping` instead of just `ping`, to demonstrate):

```
$ pingd 'http://user:pw@www.example.com:80/some/path/url?data&and#hash'
ping example.com
$ pingd 'http://www.stackexchange.com'
ping stackexchange.com
$ pingd 'http://www.stackexchange.com/help'
ping stackexchange.com
$ pingd 'https://www.stackexchange.com'
ping stackexchange.com
$ pingd 'https://unix.stackexchange.com'
ping unix.stackexchange.com
$ pingd 'https://unix.stackexchange.com/'
ping unix.stackexchange.com
$ pingd 'https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428989/allow-full-urls-starting-with-http-https-or-www-in-ping'
ping unix.stackexchange.com
$ pingd 'www.example.com'
ping example.com
```

Comment: I updated the function to use a subshell, in order to isolate the `shopt -s nocasematch`. In supporting versions of bash, this allows `pingd HTTP://wWw.example.com` to result in `ping example.com`.

Comment: Can you provide a solution in one line too?

Comment: Put semicolons between the lines? Why 1 line?

Comment: You are right. I cannot think of a use case where this need to be minified. It was just a habit from my programming for OpenWrt :) nevermind

Answer (score 1):

A fast solution to get the domain part without "http://" would be by setting `browser.urlbar.trimURLs` to `false` in Firefox's `about:config`, so you can more easily copy only the domain part of a URL.

But you can add a function `pingd` like this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
function pingd {
      ping $(echo "$1" | sed -e "s/[^/]*\/\/\([^@]*@\)\?\([^:/]*\).*/\2/" | sed "s/^www\.//")
}
```

works with:

```
pingd "http://user:pw@www.example.com:80/some/path/url?data&and#hash"
```

> PING example.com
>   ...

If the url doesn't contain `&` nor `!` it also works without quotes